# Struts Tiles ActionError

Tags: struts, nullpointerexception, tiles

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I am using Struts tiles framework to build a Web app, and i am facing a very strange problem.
I am running out of time to finish the work and if i am not able to fix this problem i will give up of using Tiles in this project.
My Tiles configuration is very simple.
In my struts-config.xml i insert the following code:

```
<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />

   <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tilesdefs.xml" />
        <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
   </plug-in>
```

In the tilesdefs.xml i have this simple code :

```
<component-definitions>
    <definition name="programarRutasTile" path="/programarRutas.jsp">
        <put name="menu" value="menu.jsp"/>
        <put name="tab" type="String" value="2"/>
    </definition>
</component-definitions>
```

And in the jsp "programarRutas.jsp" i have those three Tiles code lines:

```
<tiles:insert  name="menu">
    <tiles:put name="tabSelected"><tiles:getAsString name="tab"/></tiles:put>
</tiles:insert>
```

The menu.jsp is simple html code that make use of the tabSelected attribute passed in the programarRutas.jsp (code above).
I already try to run with all the menu.jsp page commented and the error persist.
So now will explain the error:
When i run the application and the ActionForm validate method do not find any error, the application runs normally, if the ActionForm validate method finds errors and fullfill the ActionErrors array , then the application throws the following exception :

***java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.processName...***

The only way i can run when the application finds errors is commenting the Tiles  lines code in the programarRutas.jsp

```
//<tiles:insert  name="menu">
//  <tiles:put name="tabSelected"><tiles:getAsString name="tab"/></tiles:put>
//</tiles:insert>
```

That way there is no throw exception. By those symptoms that i describe it looks like that there could be a problem in some configuration file, but i do not no for sure.
Is there anybody that could help me ???
Best regards.
Thanks in advance

Comment: After more studing , i am suspicious that is somthing related with the input attribute in the action tag in struts-config.xml.I have the following
<action path="/programarRutas"
          type="com.galpenergia.sgt.accoes.ProgramarRutasAction"
     name="programarRutasForm"
    validate="true"
    input="/programarRutas.jsp">

In the input attribute i am redirecting to programarRutas.jsp and i thing that i should redirecting to the Tiles definition , but if i put the Tiles definition name it gives me an error , is my suspicious in the right path ???

Comment: Yes, but you need to provide version information--IIRC that capability existed at one point (although I'm trying to remember back ~10 years).

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track. If Struts forwards to the layout JSP and not the tile, then the layout JSP can't know what it must insert.

Comment: I already found the problem .
My suspicious that i described in the above comment were correct.
It was missing the switch in the input attribute in the action tag in the struts-config.xml.
I switched from programarRutas.jsp to programarRutasTile and start to work.
I hope this help somebody in the future.
Thanks anyway for reading the post and specially to the Deve and JB.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The input should be the tile def, not a direct link to the JSP.